# IE7 iframe file post adding header information to file on server side

Tags: asp.net, .net, iframe, file-upload, internet-explorer-7

Why is this header information being attached to a iframe post in IE7?  The only content from the request stream should be should be the text < Team > to < COACHES >.  I want to save this as a file without that extra data.

```
POST http://localhost:2222/assets/upload? HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:2222/ncaa-certified/college-coaches-packet
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7de2531d1e0d1c
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 128632
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:2222
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=rlxvzamyz0skenb3k5wlutha

-----------------------------7de38381e0d1c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="F:\export8018160451351020928.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

< TEAM >
NAME    ADDRESS CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP
< COACHES >



-----------------------------7de38381e0d1c--
```

Answer (score 2):

an iFrame is a completely separate HTML document from the parent document, so it's going to have a full header when posted to the server.  In this case it looks like you have a multipart form being uploaded.

Can you post your HTML file and/or code and I'll respond with more details. It could be in the way that the post data is being read.